# Checking database query always returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql to host a database and I am checking in the 'favorite' table to see if an entry exists. The table is populated when a user hits a favorite button. When I run the query on postman, I echo the results from the query and even if the entry in the database exists, I am returned a NULL.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['memory_id']) && isset($_POST['uid'])) {

    // receiving the post params
            $memory_id=$_POST['memory_id'];
        $user_id=$_POST['uid'];
        echo $memory_id;
        echo $user_id;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE memory_id='$memory_id' AND user_id='$user_id'");
        if($result)
        {
         echo json_encode($result);
          // user failed to store
                $response["favorite"] = TRUE;
                echo json_encode($response);


        }
            else {
                    $response["favorite"]=FALSE;
            echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }


  else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters user or memory is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: I would inspect your $result a little closer. Just because if($result) doesn't return false doesn't mean you retrieved results. And you aren't calling any fetch methods so you didn't request data from the database. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-fetch.php

Comment: check for errors on it, you'll see for yourself and you're not doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to call some mysqli fetch function (like mysqli_fetch_assoc):

```
$q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE memory_id='$memory_id' AND user_id='$user_id'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
if($result)
{
     echo json_encode($result);
......
```

NOTE: is assume your favorite::memory_id and favorite::user_id columns are VARCHAR types

Comment: I tried it before, but when I tried your it worked. Thank you.